# How to fetch user roles via JWT token when authenticate user with Google

Tags: jwt, openid-connect, google-apps, google-authentication, federated-identity

I'm trying to use Google as an IDP for my application by federation.

For user authentication part i'm using openID connect flow.

Following steps have been done already.

- Created a Google application
- Got client ID and client secret
- Configured Google federation in my application (Login with google)
- Authentication flow is successfully working
- Token retrieved successfully

The problem is I want to add user roles to the user that already registered in google and fetch the user roles as a claim in token that is retrieve from the google.

Basically I want do add role based authentication to the application based on user roles.

**So how to create and assign user roles to Google user, and how to fetch them as a claim in JWT token?**

Comment: Hi. I have the same problem. Did you found a solution for this ?